# Ant javac ignore missing imports

Tags: java, ant, javac

i am trying to port a build from Eclipse to use "standalone" ant, there are a lot of linked files/folders and also some cycle references(If i export via Eclipse it is working).

I was trying to find a way to make the javac ignore if a java file was not found.

Is this even possible with ant?
And if not, is there any chance i could be able to get a working build perhaps with an other build tool?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying to find a way to make the javac ignore if a java file was not found.

Don't. Instead, make sure you supply all the code you need.

What would you expect the compiler to do if you start using a type which it knows nothing about? Java just isn't designed to cope with the situation.

If Eclipse can build the code without errors, then everything *should* be available - you should track down every missing file rather than trying to ignore them.

Comment: ok, do you maybe know how i can "temporarily" use a file than?
Because in Eclipse the project is configured to include another project, which is done by just including the projects source files in a jar. And this included jar is what i am trying to build, but if i include all files they show up in the jar as well...

Comment: @MatthiasG: Your description is confusing, but I would start off with the "innermost" dependency first: the one that doesn't depend on any other projects. Don't waste time trying to find ways of ignoring build errors - instead, start off with one small thing, get *that* working, then move on.

Comment: Add the second project's output directory to the classpath of this project?

Comment: I don't understand the problem... if this is source files can't you compile the dependencies then use it in your javac classpath ?

Comment: well i think i have to handle the cycle references first to be able to start with the innermost dependency
thanks to all of you